# How to transition an angularJS application to angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-controller

I currently have a simple search functionality defined in AngularJS (https://next.plnkr.co/edit/qpyvZuvI8vw8q6on?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview) but I'm hoping to migrate this feature into an existing Angular application.  I created a new Angular application and moved the view into `app.component.html`

```
  <head>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <h1> Search Feature </h1>

  <body ng-app="search" ng-cloak>
     <div id="content" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input type='text' ng-model='searchText' placeholder=" Enter Query Here  " />  
          <ul>
            <li class="angular-with-newlines" ng-repeat="course in courses | filter:searchText"> 
              {{course.course_number}}: {{course.title}}
              <button ng-click="course.showDesc=!course.showDesc">See More</button> 
              <div ng-if="course.showDesc"> Description: {{course.description}} </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I then moved the controller code into a javascript file called `script.js`

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('search', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.courses = [
        {
            id: 1,
      course_number: '54 Mathematics',
      title: 'Linear Algebra and Differential Equations',
      description: 'Basic linear algebra; matrix arithmetic and determinants. Vector spaces; inner product as spaces.',
      keywords: 'determinants, linear, equations, inner, basic, spaces, partial, order'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
      course_number: '110 Mathematics',
      title: 'Linear Algebra',
      description: "Matrices, vector spaces, linear transformations, inner products, determinants.",
      keywords: "determinants, forms, products, eigenvectors, linear"
        },
        {
           id: 3,
      course_number: '89A Statistics',
      title: 'Linear Algebra for Data Science',
      description: 'An introduction to linear algebra for data science.',
      keywords: 'ranking, prob, network, document, algebra, basics, model, matrices,'
        }

    ];
});
```

However, I can't access any of the data defined in the controller and the application doesn't work.  I'm relatively new to web development, so will this not work because I need to convert my javascript code into typescript?  Or do I need to somehow import my code in a different way?

Any input is appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: If you are new to angular, you should be aware that AngularJS (version<2) and Angular (version>=2) is similar in name only. None of the syntax is compatible. At the time a lot of criticism was that they should have gone with a new name instead of trying to piggy ride on any popularity with AngularJS. But I guess it worked for them. The HTML-templates are somewhat similar, and often you'll find equivalents if you search for things like "how to use `ng-`something in angular 2". I'm guessing that filter is no good though. Declaring module, controller and injecting scope is all different.

Comment: Give this a read:
https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Comment: Both are pretty much different. You might have to rewrite everything... Even Angular has changed a lot from it's alpha release and 1.5 years back it was really frustrating for the developers whether to go with Angular or not as everything was changing so quickly with every update. But all thanks to God that the current framework is pretty much stable.

There's always a possibility for new things to come but that's not going to impact the already written code as the Angular team is also concerned regarding the backward compatibility.

Comment: Yeah, and even if you see "angular 2, 4, 5, 6" it's only because of [semver](https://semver.org/) and they are almost the same and backwards compatible most of the time. It's just 1.x that is an entirely different beast.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to learn some angular, so I tried to convert this as a learning effort. Step by step:

1. Create new project `ng new test`
2. There are pipe-functions in angular, but no pipe-filter so we have to create one. (cd test) `ng generate pipe search` (I found this by listing all things generatable `ng generate --help`.
3. After some searching I learned that to use "ng-model" you add the "FormsModule" to your app. In app.module.ts: `import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";` and update @NgModule imports: `...  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ], ...`.
4. Updated `app.component.html` to use our template:

`<div id="content">
      <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='searchText' placeholder=" Enter Query Here" />
      <ul>
        <li class="angular-with-newlines" *ngFor="let course of courses | Search:searchText">
            {{course.course_number}}: {{course.title}}
            <button (click)="course.showDesc=!course.showDesc">See More</button> 
            <div *ngIf="course.showDesc"> Description: {{course.description}} </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>`

If you knew how your old template works then I think those changes are self-explanatory. It took a little bit of research, but almost everything is equivalent with AngularJS and has just a few changes to syntax.

5. Controller as well. No more scope, just declare a variable straight in the controller. And add the search input model of course:

`import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    @Component({
      selector: "app-root",
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = "app";
      searchText = "Math"; // Just a default value
      courses = [{ id: 1, course_number:  ...}, ...];  // Snip for readability
    }`

6. And finally implement our search filter. You'll need to put the most work in here (if you want to mimic the old filter exactly anyway.

search.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
  name: "Search",
  pure: false
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchValue: string, filter: Object): any {
    return items.filter(item => {
      return item.title.indexOf(searchValue) > -1 ||
             item.course_number.indexOf(searchValue) > -1;
    });
  }
}
```

I used indexOf and es6 filter to create something simple - here only looking at two fields and it's not case insensitive. I had to set `pure` to `false` to get it to update correctly. Which suggests to me that a pipe might not be the optimal way to do things. Perhaps a controller function triggered by model changes (with debounce) and create a results-array would be a better idea.

**Additional note:** Using NgModel is probably overkill since it binds a value two-ways (from controller to template and from template to controller) but we never change the value (other than to set a default), so skipping ngModel and use `(change)="doSearch()"` would be one import less, and maybe cleaner but I guess less modular than the filter.

Answer (score 2):

I've create a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe). Look into **app.component.ts** , **app.component.html**, **app.module.ts** and **course-filter.pipe.ts**

In Angular there is a thing called [Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) . A pipe takes in data as input and transforms it to a desired output. There are some [built in pipes](https://angular.io/api?type=pipe) and also you can create your own [custom pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes). for your scenario we have to create a custom pipe.

Most of your html can be reused. But you have to replace `filter` functionality with a Angular `pipe`.

You have to create a pipe like this and declare it a `ngModule`.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Course } from './app.component';

@Pipe({
  name: 'courseFilter'
})
export class CourseFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(courses: Course[], keyword: string): Course[] {
    debugger;
    if (!keyword || keyword === '') {
      return courses;
    }
    return courses.filter((course: Course) => {
      return course.course_number.toString().includes(keyword) ||
        course.description.includes(keyword) || 
        course.keywords.includes(keyword) || 
        course.title.includes(keyword)
    });
  }
}
```

The app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { CourseFilter } from './course-filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, CourseFilter ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You add the FormsModule to the list of imports defined in the @NgModule decorator. This gives the application access to all of the template-driven forms features, including ngModel.

BrowserModule is a module that provides all kinds of services and directives one usually wants to use in an Angular2 application like ngIf.

And your template should like this.

```
  <h1> Search Feature </h1>

 <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='searchText' placeholder=" Search a Topic, Subject, or a Course!" >

<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let course of courses | courseFilter: searchText">
       {{course.course_number}} :      {{course.title}} <br>
       <button (click)="course.showDescription = !course.showDescription">See More</button>
       <div *ngIf="course.showDescription">
         {{course.description}}
       </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Since I just tried to implement the same (its fun just to note the differences). I  thought I'd poke some questions. What does the CommonModule do here? A quick search says it's for basics such as ngFor and ngIF, but it seems to run fine without, so is it just a best practice thing to show what you are using?

Comment: @ippi Actually we dont need to import `CommonModule` in here. But we need to import `Formsmodule` as we are using `[(ngModule)]` in the application. I will update the answer with descriptiions. Any way thanks for pointing out

Comment: Just to be clear I understand, I added another pipe for highlighting the search result within the course title, description, and keywords, but it doesn't seem to work. (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-cjqrbc) Is it different if I want to use a pipe on interpolated values?  Highlighting filter from here (https://gist.github.com/adamrecsko/0f28f474eca63e0279455476cc11eca7#gistcomment-2103489)   Thank you!

Comment: Its working fine.. Add some css and it should work. You are perfectly replacing the letters with `<span class="highlight">letter or word</span>`. Inspect the elements and see. I think the issue is with the styling. Add some css.